# Azure DevOps & Logic Apps - Add comment

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I've configured my logic apps to wait for HTTP request, parse JSON and then add the comment to specific work Item with the values from the request. Everything works fine, but in work item, the comment is always added with my identity.

How can I change the Identity / User of the new comment to something generic - e.g. 'auto-bot' ?

Comment: could you explain a little more ind etaisl what you are trying to achieve ? share your logic app flow/definition ? what do mean by work item/comment ?

Answer (score 0):

The connection of Flow action is created based on a personal account. If you configures the Update item action, then the author of the added comment you.

You can look for two Options: (preferred option 2)

1. Please consider adding tags to Comments, **like: Comment by “Auto-Bot”** (based on your HTTP request)
2. Create an Service Account User in Azure DevOps and add DevOps connector using service account. Then when comment is added to worktime, it would be added by service account and not your name.

Reference to create the Service Accounts:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-ad-groups?view=azure-devops-2020#to-create-an-account-to-use-as-a-service-account-in-active-directory
2. https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/devopsserver/azureserviceprincipal/